# Solving $\int^{+ \infty}_{- \infty} \exp(-x-e^{-x})dx= \frac{1}{c}$

Tags: probability, integration, limits

I need to solve an equation.
$\int^{+ \infty}_{- \infty} \exp(-x-e^{-x})dx= \frac{1}{c}$

I know that 
$\int^{+\infty}_{-\infty} \exp(-x-e^{-x})dx= \lim_{a \rightarrow -\infty} \int^{0}_{a} \exp(-x-e^{-x})dx + \lim_{b {\rightarrow \infty}} \int^{b}_{0} \exp(-x-e^{-x})dx$

Can somebody explain step by step how to integrate $\int \lim_{a \rightarrow -\infty} \int^{a}_{0} \exp(-x-e^{-x})dx $
 I used variable exchange method and I got 
$\lim_{a \rightarrow -\infty} (e-e^{-a})$.

Is it right?  But how to solve this limit?

Comment: Are you sure about your limit expansion? Should they not be $a \rightarrow \infty$ and $b \rightarrow -\infty$?

Answer (score 6):

This isn't an integral equation---it's just doing an integral. Change variable $u=e^{-x}$, and you get 1.

Answer (score 1):

we have:
$$I=\int\exp\left(-x-e^{-x}\right)dx$$
$$=\int e^{-x-e^{-x}}dx$$
$u=e^{-x}$ so $dx=\frac{du}{-e^{-x}}$
$$I=-\int e^{-u}du=e^{-u}+C=e^{-e^{-x}}+C$$
now put in limits